# After redirecting route to 'thank-you' component, I want the user to be able to hit browser back button to go back to home

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple React app and am using React-Router to redirect to a thank-you component on successful form submit. This works great but when a user hits the browser back button or refresh, it keeps the thank you component loaded but removes the route. I do have a variable in app state called 'formSubmitted" that gets changed to true when the form submits and displays switches out the main home component for the thank you component. So I am guessing that is staying true on back button click or refresh. Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried using  PerformanceNavigation.type == 2 or 1 in an IF statement to check for the click and then setState of formSubmitted back to false but has not worked.

```
Router.js

    const Router = () => (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/thank-you" component={App} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );

App.js

 class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formSubmitted: false,
      zip: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        {this.state.formSubmitted === false ? (
          <div>
            <Banner>
            <Form/>
          </div>
          ) : (
          <ThankYouMessage />
        )}

Form.js - This is wrapped with withRouter

    fetch(submissionUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        body: json,
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }).then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
          this.props.history.push('/thank-you');
          return response;
        } else {
          console.log("Somthing went wrong");
        }
      });
```

I don't know if I need to wrap the app.js withRouter or what is best.

Comment: Add exact to your `/` route as well.

Comment: Where exactly are you setting the ```formSubmitted``` to true?

Comment: I am setting it in app.js using this:                                      
  onFormSubmit(updatedZip) {
    this.setState({
      formSubmitted: true,
      zip: updatedZip
    });
  }                                                                                               it is being passed into the form component as a prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your app.js to this,

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      zip: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
         <div>
            <Banner>
            <Form/>
        </div>
     </div>
        )}
```

The way you've written your app component is that it also contains the `Thankyou` component. When you set the `formSubmitted` to true, because of your conditional logic, `App` component will still show `Thankyou` component and not the `Form`.

Comment: Gotcha, this is what I was thinking the answer would be. Thanks for the help!